# need help in editing data in csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, spreadsheet

I am in need of editing the date data in csv.

I will explain [with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxU1k.png).

[image]

I am using WPS presentation software for reading and editing csv files. If the above is not possible in that, i can also use MS excel software .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in Excel you can add one second. So for example:

= A1 + B1

B1 = 00:01

This worked for me. You have to put this 00:01 into a separate cell to make sure it is a time value.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I followed the steps. but i am getting something else as output. check the image
http://s14.postimg.org/xj1ajof81/Untitled.png

those are three sceenshots in same image....

Comment: The formula returns a number in column C. This is because Excel stores dates as numbers. If you would change the settings of the cells in column C to date/time values you will see the result you are looking for

Comment: yes as you said the C cell was in number format. Once i change it to date format it worked perfectly. Now i understand it clearly. thanks for spending time in answering my question. Have a great day..

Answer (score 0):

In Excel to obtain 2 rows and 1 increment in hour:

```
           Column A
```

**1** 18/05/2015  12:00:00

**2** 18/05/2015  12:00:00

in A3 write the following formula =IF(A1=A2;A2+(1/24);A2), then copy paste this formula for the rows you need.